# how can remove extra black spacing on header or footer while build ios in ionic framework?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic 2.2.1version. When I used on Ionic or run my project on browser everything is perfect, but when I build iOS apk extra black spacing is coming on header or footer. Android is also perfect apk. please tell me if anyone have a solution.

screenshot on iOS simulator like this:

[image: screenshot on ios simulator]

Comment: can you post picture of ios simulator

Comment: @varun aaruru any updates regarding the same?

Comment: I encountered this problem in native ios application and solved it by updating launchscreen and icon files

Comment: @Avtarsingh try debugging with your safari and select that black space to see what element is causing it. this way you can find out what css property is causing it.

Comment: its working thanks @varun aaruru

Comment: **Just Follow** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232812/cordova-app-not-displaying-correctly-on-iphone-x-simulator/46232813
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232812/cordova-app-not-displaying-correctly-on-iphone-x-simulator