# Cordova app not displaying correctly on iPhone X (Simulator)

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap, iphone-x

I tested my Cordova-based app yesterday on the iPhone X Simulator in Xcode 9.0 (9A235) and it didn't look good. 
Firstly, instead of filling the full screen area, there was a black area above and below the app content.
And worse, between the app content and the black was two white bars.

Adding `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine` so Cordova renders using WKWebView (not UIWebView) fixes the white bars.
By my app is not migrated from UIWebView to WKWebView due to performance and memory leak issues when using `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine` which occur when loading images downloaded from Inapp Purchase hosted content into an HTML5 canvas (direct `file://` access by the Webview is not possible due to security restrictions in WKWebView so the image data must be loaded via `cordova-plugin-file`).

These screenshots show a test app with a blue background set on the `<body`>. 
Above and below UIWebView, you can see the white bars, but not with WKWebView:

[image]
<sub>(source: [pbrd.co](https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/GKeaEPg.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [pbrd.co](https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/GKeaWwK.png))</sub>

Both Cordova Webviews exhibit the black areas when compared to a native app which fills the full screen area:

[image]

Comment: Interesting with wkwebview. In my game, i had it not full width, but also offset from center. In uiwebview it kept the same size, but centers itself at least.

Comment: I had this problem too so i made some workaround with just css see https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/263460/55076

Comment: I am having this problem too.  Just adding the `<meta>` tag to my cordova index.hml file as others listed below is not working.  I am running Cordova 7x with cordova-ios 4.5.4 - is there anything else I need to be doing?

Answer (score 260, accepted):

I found the solution to the white bars [here](http://stephenradford.me/removing-the-white-bars-in-safari-on-iphone-x/):

Set `viewport-fit=cover` on the viewport `<meta>` tag, i.e.:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, viewport-fit=cover">
```

The white bars in UIWebView then disappear:

[image]

The solution to remove the black areas (provided by [@dpogue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/558822/dpogue) in a comment below) is to use [LaunchStoryboard images](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/index.html#launch-storyboard-images) with `cordova-plugin-splashscreen` to replace the legacy launch images, used by Cordova by default. To do so, add the following to the iOS platform in `config.xml`:

```
<platform name="ios">    
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone~anyany.png" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone~comany.png" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone~comcom.png" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@3x~iphone~anyany.png" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@3x~iphone~anycom.png" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@3x~iphone~comany.png" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~ipad~anyany.png" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~ipad~comany.png" />   

    <!-- more iOS config... -->
</platform>
```

Then create the images with the following dimensions in `res/screen/ios` (remove any existing ones):

```
Default@2x~iphone~anyany.png - 1334x1334
Default@2x~iphone~comany.png - 750x1334
Default@2x~iphone~comcom.png - 1334x750
Default@3x~iphone~anyany.png - 2208x2208
Default@3x~iphone~anycom.png - 2208x1242
Default@3x~iphone~comany.png - 1242x2208
Default@2x~ipad~anyany.png - 2732x2732
Default@2x~ipad~comany.png - 1278x2732
```

Once the black bars are removed, there's another thing that's different about the iPhone X to address: The status bar is larger than 20px due to the "notch", which means any content at the far top of your Cordova app will be obscured by it:

[image]

Rather than hard-coding a padding in pixels, you can handle this automatically in CSS using the new `safe-area-inset-*` constants in iOS 11.

**Note:** in iOS 11.0 the function to handle these constants was called `constant()` but in iOS 11.2 Apple renamed it to `env()` ([see here](https://webkit.org/blog/7929/designing-websites-for-iphone-x/)), 
therefore to cover both cases you need to overload the CSS rule with both and rely on the [CSS fallback mechanism](https://modernweb.com/using-css-fallback-properties-for-better-cross-browser-compatibility/) to apply the appropriate one:

```
body{
    padding-top: constant(safe-area-inset-top);
    padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top);
}
```

The result is then as desired: the app content covers the full screen, but is not obscured by the "notch":

[image]

I've created a Cordova test project which illustrates the above steps: [webview-test.zip](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12887293/webview-test.zip)

**Notes:**

Footer buttons

- If your app has footer buttons (as mine does), you will also need to apply `safe-area-inset-bottom` to avoid them being overlapped by the virtual Home button on iPhone X.
- In my case, I couldn't apply this to `<body>` as the footer is absolutely positioned, so I needed to apply it directly to the footer:

```
.toolbar-footer{
    margin-bottom: constant(safe-area-inset-bottom);
    margin-bottom: env(safe-area-inset-bottom);
}
```

cordova-plugin-statusbar

- The status bar size has changed on iPhone X, so older versions of `cordova-plugin-statusbar` display incorrectly on iPhone X
- [Mike Hartington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2055617/mhartington) has created [this pull request](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar/pull/85) which applies the necessary changes.
- This was merged into the `cordova-plugin-statusbar@2.3.0` release, so make sure you're using at least this version to apply to safe-area-insets

splashscreen

- The LaunchScreen storyboard constraints changed on iOS 11/iPhone X, meaning the splashscreen appeared to "jump" on launch when using existing versions of the plugin ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47467176/777265)).
- This was captured in bug report [CB-13505](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13505), fixed PR [cordova-ios#354](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/pull/345) and released in [`cordova-ios@4.5.4`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/releases/tag/4.5.4), so make sure you're using a recent version of the `cordova-ios` platform.

device orientation

- When using UIWebView on iOS 11.0, rotating from portrait > landscape > portrait causes the `safe-area-inset` not to be re-applied, causing the content to be obscured by the notch again (as highlighted by [jms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4549832/jms) in a comment below).
- Also happens if app is launched in landscape then rotated to portrait
- This doesn't happen when using WKWebView via `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine`.
- Radar report: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5035192880201728
- **Update**: this appears to have been fixed in iOS 11.1

For reference, this is the original Cordova issue I opened which captures this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13273

Comment: I added a comment to the Cordova issue, but for anyone finding this here: To remove the black bars and take the full screen height, you must use a LaunchStoryboard instead of splash screen images. This is supported by newer versions of Cordova: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/index.html#launch-storyboard-images

Comment: @dpogue thanks, I've tried this and it works: will update the answer to include it

Comment: Do you have any issues when you rotate the screen? I've been trying, but after rotate screen, everything is broken (safe-area-inset-* doesn't update their values depending device orientation; and after rotate portrait -> landscape -> portrait again, the initial values are broken too). Could it be some issue with apple/safari browser?

Comment: @jms I hadn't tested this (my affected production app is fixed in portrait) but yes, I can reproduce the issue in the above test app: rotating from portrait > landscape > portrait, the initial safe-inset value appears to be no longer applied. Will update my answer with a note on this.

Comment: @DaveAlden thanks for checking it, at least it's not something happening just in my computer. Hope apple fixes it in final iOS 11 version...

Comment: To get rid of the black bars specifically, I had one splash screen that was called `Default@2x~universal~anyany.png` and I just had to rename `@2x` to `@3x`. My splash screen image is a 10x10 solid color, which is why this works I guess. But otherwise the list of different splash screens you specified is probably better.

Comment: Not working for me: I add `viewport-fit=cover` on the viewport `<meta>` tag. After i delete `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine` plugin white space is gone .But I need this plugin in my app. My issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46494221/ionic-white-space-in-bottom-with-wkwebview-in-ios-11

Comment: @jms I've seen the same, created a Jira issue and pull request here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar/pull/88

Comment: In my case, when I added `viewport-fit=cover` my whole app just shows a blank white screen and nothing else. I'm using iOS11, Xcode9 on iPhone 7 Plus. Anyone experiencing similar behavior?

Comment: Wanted to thank you for this solution as it seems to work fine, using your suggestion and using the modded version of status bar along with view port suggestion fixed this issue. The only issue i had was     padding-top: constant(safe-area-inset-top); which didnt work unless i used margain-bottom which then threw all my other devices off, my suggestion for anyone having to use the same is dynamically detect if its an iphone X (height is 812px) load some extra css into the document which does as seen above only on the iphone X

Comment: We've implemented these fixes which look fantastic in the emulator, but for some reason are failing on-device. We're applying specialized styles using device-detection (viewport height), which might not be reliable, it looks like. Trying to get access to a physical device.

Comment: @Brent if you (or anyone else) has access to a physical device, can you confirm which of the above fixes are not working. So far I've only been able to test on Simulator.

Comment: @DaveAlden - it looks that in 11.2 beta+ they've dropped `constant` for `env` keyword -- see also: https://webkit.org/blog/7929/designing-websites-for-iphone-x/

Comment: This only worked for me, once I switch to Ionic's WebView. https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar/pull/87#issuecomment-332250769

Comment: .element { margin-bottom: constant(safe-area-inset-bottom); margin-bottom: env(safe-area-inset-bottom); } doesn't work for me. On iOS 11.1, it just makes the margin-bottom 0.

Comment: where do you put the body css code in your App? Like in which file? Nothing works for me, I'm using Ionic 3.

Comment: Please note that that the app needs to be build with Cordova `cli-7.0.0` or higher! Took me a while to figure out that build.phonegap.com uses `cli-6.5.0` by default.

Comment: @Sander - Cordova 7x is required, but is there a base cordova-ios that is needed as well?

Comment: For now I am only interested in fixing the white bars above and below.  Is all that is needed is the `<meta>` tag in the header of the index.html file to do this?  Because I added that and I am still getting the white bars.  Not certain what to do now.  I can tell my DIV is going further down behind the lower white bar because there is no border showing at the bottom and some text at the very bottom of the DIV isn't showing.  So I know its there, but the white bar is covering it.

Comment: But I have the blackbars NOT on a splashpage, so the solution to use the larger splash page images is not applicable. Its in my app itself, no splash image showing.

Comment: @DaveAlden After updating the splashscreens following your guide, my splashscreen configurations are ignored and the splashscreen is displaying only for a short time causing a white screen to be shown before the app is loaded. I've created a question but so far no one has the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50951069/cordova-ios-splashscreen-configurations-ignored I hope you can help me with your experience. Thank you

Comment: If you are using WKWebView and still facing bars at the bottom, set `body { height: 100vh; }`.

Comment: I was wondering if this is backward compatible with older iPhones? So if i made this work for iPhone x what would happen if the app was installed on say iPhone 6?

Comment: @GlenElkins The value is 0 on older iPhones.

Comment: Is there any update regarding the rotation problem? I'm on iOS 12 and experiencing the same issue. Looks strange to me that this problem persists. /cc @jms

Comment: Is it possible to test it in xcode simulator? According to cordova-plugin-splashscreen docs "Simulator may not show expected images when launched from CLI ". I've tried, and in simulator black bars are still present.

Comment: I have an ionic app so I placed all the images in `resources/splash/ios` - if I create the `res/screen/ios` folder the images don't work.  HOWEVER, it looks like its choosing the wrong image because the image isn't sized properly...it fills the whole screen and looks squished even with the outside edges of the image being cutoff.  Any thoughts?

Comment: now on a regular iPhone 6 (12.3) I get the same huge, over sized, skewed splash screen and then after a few seconds its shows the normal one.  I then removed all new (above) splash screen references and files and its still happening.

Comment: I got it all working however on the iPhone 6 its still showing a cached splash screen image - that image doesn't even exist in the app anymore.  I deleted the app, rebooted the phone, reinstalled the app but its still showing - after the wrong big/skewed one shows it then shows the correct image properly sized.  I can't get rid of the cached one.

Comment: For anyone sharing my above issue or having issues on an Ionic app related to this, after compiling I found OLD splash screen files in this folder: `platforms/ios/myApp/Images/xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/` - also check the `LaunchStoryboard.imageset` folder and ensure all your images are correct.  I found two files still showing the default cordova icon (Default-2436h.png and Default-Landscape-2436h.png) - I created two new image files of those Width/Height dimensions and copied over those two files.  Everything is working now.

Comment: Having White Space issue on Inner pages where i have no `ion-header` tags. it shows white space on top. but on other screens its working fine with header / background image. but not working without header tags.

Comment: @DaveAllen - This method no longer works for iOS 13....the upper menu tabs/status bar is pushed up behind the notch.

Answer (score 39):

*For a manual fix to an existing cordova project*

**The black bars**

Add this to your **info.plist** file. Fixing the launch image is a separate issue i.e. [How to Add iPhoneX Launch Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46191522/how-to-add-iphonex-launch-image)

```
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>CDVLaunchScreen</string>
```

**The white bars**

Set viewport-fit=cover in the meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, viewport-fit=cover">
```

Comment: Thanks! The .plist change has the same effect as the changes from the selected answer, but WAY faster.

Comment: What does each of these tasks do to CSS pixel height and width?  My app has a series of narrow divs at the top (menus, etc)...and then I calculate the remaining pixel height to have the last DIV fill the rest of the screen.  Right now I can see the lower white bar cover some of that DIV, but I can also tell not all of it - implying the DIV is still not going to the bottom of the screen. And in turn, my app starts below the upper white bar so its not even trying to use the upper space.

Comment: I used `UILaunchStoryboardName` and it managed to remove the black bars. But my splash screen gets expanded. Any reason why? The accepted answer isn't working for me

Comment: @coder Thanks - but adding the UILaunchStoryboardName to the plist stops me from being able to submit to the app store: ERROR ITMS-90705: "Launch storyboard not found. Make sure you specify the launch storyboard filename without a filename extension for the key UILaunchStoryboardName in the Info.plist."

Comment: @Huiting did you find any solution about your case?

Comment: @LMaker since this was almost 1 yr ago, I cant really remember. But I think it was because the splash screen size was not yet catered for iPhone X. I believed I redid a new splashscreen with the required dimensions

Comment: If I use this, I got the error "the bundle does not contain an app icon for ipad of exactly '167x167' pixels"... why?

Comment: All that always gets overwritten with the next ionic prepare command, UILaunchStoryboardName and it’s value CDVLaunchScreen is being removed by ionic prepare command. :(

Answer (score 18):

### There is 3 steps you have to do

for iOs 11 status bar & iPhone X header problems

---

**1. Viewport fit cover**

Add `viewport-fit=cover` to your viewport's meta in `<header>`

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=0,viewport-fit=cover">
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/gq5pt509 (index.html)

---

2. **Add more splash images** to your `config.xml` inside `<platform name="ios">`

**Dont skip this step**, this required for getting **screen fit** for **iPhone X** work

```xml
<splash src="your_path/Default@2x~ipad~anyany.png" />   <!-- 2732x2732 -->
<splash src="your_path/Default@2x~ipad~comany.png" />   <!-- 1278x2732 -->
<splash src="your_path/Default@2x~iphone~anyany.png" /> <!-- 1334x1334 -->
<splash src="your_path/Default@2x~iphone~comany.png" /> <!-- 750x1334  -->
<splash src="your_path/Default@2x~iphone~comcom.png" /> <!-- 1334x750  -->
<splash src="your_path/Default@3x~iphone~anyany.png" /> <!-- 2208x2208 -->
<splash src="your_path/Default@3x~iphone~anycom.png" /> <!-- 2208x1242 -->
<splash src="your_path/Default@3x~iphone~comany.png" /> <!-- 1242x2208 -->
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/mmy885q4 (config.xml)

---

3. **Fix your style on CSS**

Use `safe-area-inset-left`, `safe-area-inset-right`, `safe-area-inset-top`, or `safe-area-inset-bottom`

**Example:** (Use in your case!)

```scss
#header {
   position: fixed;
   top: 1.25rem; // iOs 10 or lower
   top: constant(safe-area-inset-top); // iOs 11
   top: env(safe-area-inset-top); // iOs 11+ (feature)

   // or use calc()
   top: calc(constant(safe-area-inset-top) + 1rem);
   top: env(constant(safe-area-inset-top) + 1rem);
  
   // or SCSS calc()
   $nav-height: 1.25rem;
   top: calc(constant(safe-area-inset-top) + #{$nav-height});
   top: calc(env(safe-area-inset-top) + #{$nav-height});
}
```

---

**Bonus:** You can add body class like `is-android` or `is-ios` on [deviceready](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html)

```
var platformId = window.cordova.platformId;
if (platformId) {
   document.body.classList.add('is-' + platformId);
}
```

So you can do something like this on CSS

```
.is-ios #header {
 // Properties
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case where each splash screen was individually designed instead of autogenerated or laid out in a story board format, I had to stick with my Legacy Launch screen configuration and add portrait and landscape images to target iPhoneX 1125×2436 orientations to the config.xml like so:

```
<splash height="2436" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-2436h.png" width="1125" />
<splash height="1125" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-2436h.png" width="2436" />
```

After adding these to config.xml ("viewport-fit=cover" was already set in index.hml) my app built with Ionic Pro fills the entire screen on iPhoneX devices.

Comment: sir but in my config.xml  i have already added above this line and viewport-fit=cover

Comment: @Kapilsoni then it might be an issue with the Cordova UIWebView, WKWebView, SplashScreen plugin, or a combination of these configurations. Also, are you targeting XCode 10 or 11 in your builds?

Comment: sir i am targeting XCode 10 ?

Answer (score 2):

Just a note that the `constant` keyword use for safe-area margins has been updated to `env` for 11.2 beta+

https://webkit.org/blog/7929/designing-websites-for-iphone-x/

Answer (score 2):

**Fix for iPhone X/XS screen rotation issue**

On iPhone X/XS, a screen rotation will cause the header bar height to use an incorrect value, because the calculation of safe-area-inset-* was not reflecting the new values in time for UI refresh. This bug exists in UIWebView even in the latest iOS 12. A workaround is inserting a 1px top margin and then quickly reversing it, which will trigger safe-area-inset-* to be re-calculated immediately. A somewhat ugly fix but it works if you have to stay with UIWebView for one reason or another.

```js
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
    var originalMarginTop = document.body.style.marginTop;
    document.body.style.marginTop = "1px";
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.body.style.marginTop = originalMarginTop;
    }, 100);
}, false);
```

The purpose of the code is to cause the document.body.style.marginTop to change slightly and then reverse it. It doesn't necessarily have to be "1px". You can pick a value that doesn't cause your UI to flicker but achieves its purpose.

Comment: UIWebView was depricated in iOS8... I doubt if any of the existing bugs will be fixed. Apple is warning when uploading apps that this will be discontinued soon... thus time to take the pain and migrate to WKWebView...

Answer (score 2):

I'm developing cordova apps for 2 years and I spent weeks to solve related problems (eg: webview scrolls when keyboard open). Here's a tested and proven solution for both ios and android

P.S.: I'm using iScroll for scrolling content

1. Never use **viewport-fit=cover** at index.html's meta tag, leave the app stay out of statusbar. iOS will handle proper area for all iPhone variants.
2. In XCode uncheck **hide status bar** and **requires full screen** and don't forget to select Launch Screen File as **CDVLaunchScreen**
3. In config.xml set **fullscreen** as **false**
4. Finally, (thanks to Eddy Verbruggen for great plugins) add his plugin [cordova-plugin-webviewcolor](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-webviewcolor) to set statusbar and bottom area background color. This plugin will allow you to set any color you want.
5. Add below to config.xml (first ff after x is opacity)

   ```
   <preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0xff088c90" />
   ```
6. Handle your scroll position yourself by adding focus events to input elements

   ```
   iscrollObj.scrollToElement(elm, transitionduration ... etc)
   ```

For android, do the same but instead of **cordova-plugin-webviewcolor**, install **cordova-plugin-statusbar** and **cordova-plugin-navigationbar-color**

Here's a javascript code using those plugins to work on both ios and android:

```
function setStatusColor(colorCode) {
    //colorCode is smtg like '#427309';
    if (cordova.platformId == 'android') {
        StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString(colorCode);
        NavigationBar.backgroundColorByHexString(colorCode);
    } else if (cordova.platformId == 'ios') {
        window.plugins.webviewcolor.change(colorCode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link, sometimes may be helpful. I could solve the issue with the solution provided below.
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine/issues/108

Add

```
[wkWebView.scrollView setContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior:UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever];
```

before wkWebView.UIDelegate = self.uiDelegate; in CDVWebViewEngine.m

Answer (score 1):

If you install newer versions of `ionic` globally you can run
`ionic cordova resources` and it will generate all of the splashscreen images for you along with the correct sizes.