# Ionic: White space in bottom with wkwebview in IOS 11

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, wkwebview

After update IOS to 11 version, I have problem with `wkwebview plugin` in my app.

Ionic command released IOS 11 [checklist](https://blog.ionic.io/ios-11-checklist/) but the problem is stay after all steps from checklist.

Ios platform version `4.4.0`

Problem on any sim iPnone 5s, 6, 6s...

In screen bottom I have white space. Helps, please.

[image]

**UPDATE**: After i delete `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine` plugin white space is gone. But I need this plugin in my app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46232812/777265

Comment: Not working for me: I add `viewport-fit=cover` on the viewport <meta> tag. After i delete `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine` plugin white space is gone .But I need this plugin in my app.

Comment: i have the same problem

Answer (score 8):

About the bottom space when using wkwebview, here is a workaround:

Add some code in cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine\src\ios\CDVWKWebViewEngine.m between line 99-100,

```
// re-create WKWebView, since we need to update configuration
WKWebView* wkWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.engineWebView.frame configuration:configuration];
//add begin
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 110000
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
  [wkWebView.scrollView setContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior:UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever];
}
#endif
//add end
wkWebView.UIDelegate = self.uiDelegate;
self.engineWebView = wkWebView;
```

The code above came from [cordova-plugin-ionic-webview](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview)

Comment: Does this workaround not included in the plugin itself? Why do we need to add separately?

Answer (score 4):

I uninstallied plugin `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine` and install `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` and it`s work perfectly.

Comment: can you please share your config.xml

Answer (score 1):

None of the provided solutions worked for me.
For iOS 11+ try the below, solved my problem.

Add the below line to your config.xml

> `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-disable-ios11-statusbar" source="npm" spec="*"/>`

Goodluck!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of disabling scrolling or forcing the removal of safe-area on the web frame, the better permanent fix is changing how Ionic stretches the app vertically on the screen. It should use a `height: 100vh` instead of `height: 100%`, per the findings in this thread: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12886

> I have new information to add to this bug, and to reiterate it is not a Cordova bug. Let me present 3 scenarios:
>
> - `viewport-fit=auto` and CSS `height: 100%` on the body element:
>   **UIWebView:** The webview is the height of the device screen, minus the unsafe area, offset at the top by the unsafe area.
>   **WKWebView:** The webview is the height of the device screen, minus the unsafe area, offset at the top by the unsafe area.
> - `viewport-fit=cover` and CSS `height: 100%` on the body element:
>   **UIWebView:** The webview is the height of the device screen.
>   **WKWebView:** The webview is the height of the safe area, showing a gap at the bottom.
> - `viewport-fit=cover` and CSS `height: 100vh` on the body element:
>   **UIWebView:** The webview is the height of the device screen.
>   **WKWebView:** The webview is the height of the device screen.

In my main SCSS file, after importing Ionic, I've set:

```css
html {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Add viewport-fit=cover to solve this problem.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```