# phonegap position:fixed content has gap at bottom

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap

I have an iOS app made with phonegap. Content displays full screen on all devices including iPhone X.

My problem is when I have a modal popup - my popup and its background are position:fixed and when displayed there is a gap at the bottom of the screen. It appears to match the size of the statusbar.

All similar posts I've found always talk about the gap occurring at the top of the webview, but for me is at the bottom.

The gap size is bigger on iPhone X than the iPhone 6, and at least in the case of the iPhone X is the precise height of many apps lower navigation bar (like facebook, whatsapp). I want my 'height:100%;position:fixed' overlay background to take up the entire screen. Any suggestions on how to remove this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried these? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46494221/ionic-white-space-in-bottom-with-wkwebview-in-ios-11

In relation to using wkwebview