# How to remove the white space at iPhone X top viewport corners on ionic cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic3, statusbar, iphone-x

I followed the instructions here [Understanding the WebView Viewport in iOS 11](https://ayogo.com/blog/ios11-viewport/) and here [Cordova app not displaying correctly on iPhone X (Simulator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232812/cordova-app-not-displaying-correctly-on-iphone-x-simulator#answer-46232813) to set viewport-fit to cover etc. But I still can't seem to get rid of these white corners on the top:

[image: screenshot]

What am I missing?

```
ionic (Ionic CLI)     : 3.15.2
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
Cordova Platforms     : ios 4.5.2
Ionic Framework       : ionic-angular 3.8.0
```

Comment: Are you using `xcode 8 or 9`?

Comment: Version 9.1 (9B55)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Eventually figured it out myself. In case anyone else has the same issue, here's what did the trick for me:

`ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-statusbar`

`ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git`

Refer to: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar/pull/85

Comment: This should have more votes, really fixing the issue.

Comment: Helped to remove the white spaces, but now the screen is way too much at the top and way too much overlapping at the bottom. Any way to "shrink it"?

Comment: It hasn't helped me, I've added a comment to the above-noted github thread.

Comment: Sometimes after a `cordova platorm rm ios && cordova platform add ios` the status plugin revert and you need to run the above commands. It took me a few hours to find this answer today :/

Answer (score 1):

Make changes in css .Add this code with existing code  like

```
body{
    padding-top: constant(safe-area-inset-top);
    padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top);
}
```

If you use toolbar button then go with:

```
.toolbar-footer{
margin-bottom: constant(safe-area-inset-bottom);
margin-bottom: env(safe-area-inset-bottom);
}
```

Solution:

[more help available at cordovo apache](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13273)

[stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232812/cordova-app-not-displaying-correctly-on-iphone-x-simulator/46232813#46232813)