# Strange visual bug at top and bottom bar with Ionic 4 and nodge iPhones

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, webview, ionic4

I built a hybrid app using Ionic 4. The app is working great in most devices but a strange bug is showing in iPhones with nodge like iPhone 11 or X.

[image]
[image]

I want to remove these top and bottom spaces. Things i have tried:

- `this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);` in the `initializeApp()`
- Add `viewport-fit=cover` to the viewport meta tag in `index.html`
- Update the Status bar plugin (cordova-plugin-statusbar)
- Add status bar directly from the github repo instead of the Ionic plugin
- Add `safe-area-inset` variables in Ionic css
- Try storyboard splash screens
- Add the status bar plugin directly from the Github repo: `ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git`
- Adding safe area

```
body{
    padding-top: constant(safe-area-inset-top);//for iOS 11.2
    padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top);//for iOS 11.1
}
```

Can i paint it black? It's working like this in Android nodge like Pixel xl.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the white space at iPhone X top viewport corners on ionic cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113436/how-to-remove-the-white-space-at-iphone-x-top-viewport-corners-on-ionic-cordova)

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work. I also made sure to remove and re-add the ios platform just in case, but no luck. I'm adding this to the tried things list.

Comment: @RicardCreagia did you find any solution for this?