# Cordova iPhone X launch image initially shows white area at bottom

Tags: ios, cordova

Anyone else had this issue? See attached images.

Cordova ios on the iPhone X simulator the launch image initially shows white area at bottom for a second and then jumps to full screen when status bar text color changes:

[image] [image]

I have `viewport-fit=cover` set and launch images are:

```
Default@2x~iphone~anyany.png (= 1334x1334 = 667x667@2x)
Default@2x~iphone~comany.png (= 750x1334 = 375x667@2x)
Default@2x~iphone~comcom.png (= 750x750 = 375x375@2x)
Default@3x~iphone~anyany.png (= 2436x2436 = 812x812@3x)
Default@3x~iphone~anycom.png (= 2436x1242 = 812x414@3x)
Default@3x~iphone~comany.png (= 1242x2436 = 414x812@3x)
Default@2x~ipad~anyany.png (= 2732x2732 = 1366x1366@2x)
Default@2x~ipad~comany.png (= 1278x2732 = 639x1366@2x)
```

Related to : [Cordova app not displaying correctly on iPhone X (Simulator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232812/cordova-app-not-displaying-correctly-on-iphone-x-simulator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed in `cordova-ios@4.5.4` (see the [release notes](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/RELEASENOTES.md)), so the solution is to update to the latest `cordova-ios` platform version:

```
cordova platform rm ios && cordova platform add ios@latest
```

It was captured in a bug report as [CB-13505](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13505) and fixed in the PR [cordova-ios#354](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/pull/345).

Comment: thanks @DaveAlden - upgrading now and will update post will outcome

Comment: Yes I can confirm upgrading to `cordova-ios@4.5.4` fixes this issue. Big thanks to `@DaveAlden`.