# Ionic - White edge on iPhone X in header

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Loading an app on iPhone X and I have white bars on the two sides of the notch. I am using Ionic Tabs. I have tried changing the body and `ion-app` background colour.

```
body, ion-app.app-root {
    background-color: color($colors, main);
}
```

First include `viewport-fit=cover`

Running `"cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.3"`

Also tried to change Statusbar background colour with `<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#25707B" />` Don't know what is causing them.

Edit: Added image of the white edge.

[image]

Comment: http://blog.ionicframework.com/ios-11-checklist/ use `viewport-fit=cover`

Comment: Apologies, forgot to add it in the description. Have that already.

Comment: oh ok..no problem can you include a screenshot in the question?

Comment: Added screenshot. Cleaned it up but its there. Thanks. Note that I'm using ionic tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The status bar size has changed on iPhone X, so older versions of `cordova-plugin-statusbar` display incorrectly on iPhone X.

[A fix](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar/pull/85) was merged into the `cordova-plugin-statusbar@2.3.0` release, so make sure you're using at least this version.
You can check which version is installed in your project by running `cordova plugin ls`.

For a more comprehensive list of issues and solutions for Cordova apps on iPhone X see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46232813/777265).

Comment: I installed the latest today v2.2.3 but I will check to upgrade.

Comment: [cordova-plugin-statusbar release notes](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar/blob/master/RELEASENOTES.md)

Comment: ran npm i cordova-plugin-statusbar and I got 2.3.0. Removed and reinstalled cordova-ios as well.