# Cordova iOS splashscreen configurations ignored

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, splash-screen

I've just reconfigured my iOS Cordova splashscreen to Launch Storyboard in order to support iPhone X. This works, but now I have a white flash between the launch storyboard and the first screen of the app. I assume this is because the splashscreen is hidden before the viewport has fully loaded.
Also my configurations not to automatically hide my splashscreen or to display it for 2 minutes are completely ignored. Why is this happening?

```
preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="20000" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="false" />
```