# iPhone X height problems

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview

I have a weird problem in my cordova app. A random bar is showing in the buttom of the screen which is impossible to place any content in. I think I have tracked down the issue to happening sometimes when you are opening the app while in a phone call on an iPhone X/XS/XS Max. I have compared the HTML-DOM and things looks exactly the same. I have set the color of the body to red for debug-purposes. Any clues where I should search for and answer?

[image: Working to the left. Problems to the right]

Comment: your app needs to respect the safe-area – probably duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232812/cordova-app-not-displaying-correctly-on-iphone-x-simulator

Comment: If I use the Safari app and I'm on a page which contains only text, the safe area is ignored (text are showed behind the home bar). I wouldn't be able to do that in my case, since sometimes this random thing shows up. So I think something is wrong here?

Comment: The text is visible, because you can scroll it - if you reached the bottom of the page no co tent should be behind the home bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a really random solution.
On boot of the app:

```
if (window.StatusBar) {
    window.StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
    window.StatusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
}
```

After that no problem!

Answer (score 0):

Check your cordova-ios version, make sure to use the storyboard splash screen and not the image based one.

Comment: I have the latest version 4.5.4. And the splash screen is working correctly. Look at the pictures, SOMETIMES I have the case to the right...

Comment: Is it WK WebView OR UI WebView?

Comment: It is WkWebView!