# White status bar using cordova-plugin-statusbar

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, statusbar, ionic-native

How can I make status bar translucent? Whatever change I make, it doesn't reflect in the app. So far I tried this.

```
StatusBar.styleLightContent();
```

I also played with StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);

The result is always this, a white status bar with no text (iOS 12, Cordova 8.1.1):

[image]

Comment: I fixed it doing this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46232813/751524
Now it also works for iPhone X

Answer (score 0):

Add these preferences to your `config.xml`

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
<preference name="StatusBarCropsWebview" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#2980b9" />
```

Full instructions and options are here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-statusbar/

Don't forget to make sure your activity indicator is set the same too.

```
<preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="white" />
```

More info on this and the available options here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html#feature