# Cordova app with Framework 7 display problems on iPhone X / XR / XS

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, cordova, html-framework-7

I'm writing an application with cordova using Framework7.
I'm on latest Cordova, Framework7, XCode, etc. version available at the moment.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to remove white statusbar and white bottom in iPhone X/XR/XS, also it stretches my framework7 navbar.

Here an image with iPhone XR Simulator running on XCode (I build in cordova then run emulator in XCode). As you can see the top white has also white text and i can't read nothing, the text becames black when i remove cordova-plugin-statusbar.

[iPhone XR Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMlZ9.jpg)

My target is to fill the whole screen, without top and bottom white bars.
I've already tryed:

- **Launch Screen:** image correctly created and located, added this in config.xml

> splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png"

- Added **viewport-fit=cover** to meta viewport tag
- Tryied with WKWebView as said in this article [Cordova app not displaying correctly on iPhone X (Simulator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232812/cordova-app-not-displaying-correctly-on-iphone-x-simulator) ,the page startes on top screen but is not long as the screen and link between pages don't work at all.

Thank you very much if you can help me.

Luca

EDIT(1):

Yes, my splash image is 2732 x 2732 
And meta viewport is:

> meta name="viewport" content=" initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,
>   minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui, viewport-fit=cover,
>   width=device-width,height=device-height"

Comment: Make sure it's the right size: `2732 x 2732`. This is what my meta tag looks like `<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width,height=device-height" />`. If the error persists try to remove the ios platform and re add it.

Comment: Yeah, it's 2732x2732, and my meta is the same as yours :(

Comment: Use https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar

Comment: Hey can you read this http://v3.framework7.io/docs/iphone-x.html may be help you.