# How to overlap image on navbar ios

Tags: ios, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

As everyone can see, in the top of the image has a blank status bar(white bar)

[image: blank space]

**My question:**

Its possible use my cover(image) over a status bar ?

**My code:**

> *profile.ts*

```
<ion-content *ngIf="showLogin == false" no-bounce class="bg-modal">
    <div class="header-image">
        <img src="../assets/imgs/Tkm-resources/Capa.png" onerror="this.src = '../assets/imgs/Tkm-resources/Capa.png'"/>
    </div>

    <div class="main-content" text-wrap text-center>

        <div class="circular">
            <img no-border src="{{ usuario.avatar }}"
                 onerror="this.src='../../assets/imgs/person-flat.png'" (click)="changePicture()"/>
        </div>
        <h6 no-margin padding-top>{{ usuario.nome }}</h6>
        <span color="ticket-grey">{{ usuario.email }}</span>
        <div>
            <ion-row margin-top  (click)="onClickLogout()">
                <ion-icon name="ios-exit" item-left color="primary"></ion-icon>
                <span margin-left> Deslogar</span>
            </ion-row>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to make it compatible and remove the top white space is:

> Add viewport-fit=cover to the viewport meta tag in index.html as
>   below:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no, width=device-width, height=device-height, viewport-fit=cover">
```

Please *ensure all the parameters are named correctly* and recheck and verify if the parameters are already added.

Also if these parameters are set correctly,*check the paddings* of the container views.

Refer these [1](https://codeburst.io/making-ionic-cordova-app-compatible-for-iphone-x-c84d62b61aa9),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232812/cordova-app-not-displaying-correctly-on-iphone-x-simulator),[3](https://stephenradford.me/removing-the-white-bars-in-safari-on-iphone-x/) for additional info and clarity.

Comment: bar still blank... :(!

Comment: Could you try changing the BG color of ion-content and observe the color of status bar.

Comment: Also ,the issue is probably due to styling.

Comment: @PéttrinMiranda did you try changing bg color.